# How do I create a huxtable table caption using bookdown in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, captions

I have numerous [huxtable](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html) tables in my rmarkdown.  I'd like to caption them using [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html).  So far I've been unable to do this using the bookdown instructions for "other R packages to generate tables" (see URL above).

Here's an example which follows the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723514/referencing-a-hand-made-table-using-bookdown-package):

````
---
title: "huxtable-mwe"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::html_book
documentclass: book
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(huxtable)
library(magrittr)
```

See table \@ref(tab:bar).

Table (\#tab:foo): Foo

```{r foo, echo=FALSE}
ht <- hux(
  foo = c('foo','bar')
) %>%
  set_all_borders(1)
ht
```

See table \@ref(tab:foo).

Table (\#tab:bar): Bar

```{r bar, echo=FALSE}
ht <- hux(
  foo = c('bar', 'baz')
) %>%
  set_all_borders(1)
ht
```
````

References work, but I get the following table captions:

Table (#tab:foo): Foo

Table (#tab:bar): Bar

when I expected:

Table 1: Foo

Table 2: Bar

Grateful for a MWE.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved.  Use `set_caption(...)` to get the caption into a `<caption>...</caption>` element, and don't escape the label:

````
---
title: "huxtable-mwe"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::html_book
documentclass: book
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(huxtable)
library(magrittr)
```

See table \@ref(tab:bar).

```{r foo, echo=FALSE}
ht <- hux(
  foo = c('foo','bar')
) %>%
  set_all_borders(1) %>%
  set_caption('(#tab:foo) Foo')
ht
```

See table \@ref(tab:foo).

```{r bar, echo=FALSE}
ht <- hux(
  foo = c('bar', 'baz')
) %>%
  set_all_borders(1) %>%
  set_caption('(#tab:bar) Bar')
ht
```
````