# Huxtable package for R: How to correctly reference huxtables in bookdown?

Tags: r

Compiling a report with bookdown I encounter difficulties in referencing tables generated with the huxtable package. For my work,  LaTex/PDF, as well as an HTML version of the report, need to be created.

When rendering the document knitr::is_XXX_output() selects the optimal way to display the tables, see MWE:

````
```{r chunk-label, results='asis', fig.cap='chunk-caption'}
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B"), each=2)), 
                   rating = c(rnorm(2),rnorm(2, mean=.8)))

hux <- as_hux(dat)                    %>%
  set_caption('hux caption')          %>% 
  set_label("tab:hux-label")                                              

if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  print_html(hux)   # output table html friendly (requires in chunk options "results='asis'")
}
if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  hux
}
```
````

I am not sure whether it is recommended to use the caption and label commands provided by huxtable

```
  set_caption('pipe caption') and set_label("tab:hux-label")
```

or knitr

```
  chunk-label and fig.cap='chunk caption'
```

For figures, the latter works very well, but unfortunately not for tables.

The hook for "tab.cap" as discussed in following did not work well with bookdown and if PDF & HTML are needed.
[Using table caption on R markdown file using knitr to use in pandoc to convert to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258233/using-table-caption-on-r-markdown-file-using-knitr-to-use-in-pandoc-to-convert-t)

Help and recommendations are very much appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what your actual question is, but this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318658/how-do-i-create-a-huxtable-table-caption-using-bookdown-in-rmarkdown

Comment: Thank you very much @dash2 for your reply. My aim is to generate huxtables with labels and captions, which work for both HTML and LaTeX output.
In HTML I can use `set_caption('(#tab:setcaption) my caption')` which works without problems. 
In LaTeX/PDF I can use `set_caption('(\\#tab:setcaption) caption')` – which works for one figure only. If I include two figures I get `! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.`
Also, `set_label()` from the huxtable package does not help much as it does not work in bookdown AFAIK. Anyone have an idea, maybe on how to circumvent the float error?

Comment: also `hux <- add_footnote(hux, 'my footnote')` is not working in bookdown, yielding the following error: `Error in if (! Attr (input, "format")% in% c ("html", "latex")) {:   Argument has length 0`

Comment: See https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to huxtable 4.3.0 (now on CRAN), it automatically takes care of bookdown table captions for you. Here's a short example:

````
---
title: "Bookdown test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book: default
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(dplyr)
library(huxtable)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

```

My table is \@ref(tab:foo1). The other table is \@ref(tab:foo2). The third is \@ref(tab:foo3).

```{r}


hux(a = 1:5, b = 1:5) %>% 
  set_caption("My labelled table") %>% 
  set_label("tab:foo1")

hux(a = 1:5, b = 1:5) %>% 
  set_caption("My unlabelled table")

hux(a = 1:5, b = 1:5) %>% 
  set_caption("My labelled table, prefix should be autoadded!") %>% 
  set_label("foo2")

hux(a = "A table with no caption, but a label") %>% 
  set_label("tab:foo3")

hux(a = "A table with no caption or label")

```
````

Not everything is perfect. If you set `echo = TRUE` you will need to manually insert `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{fancyvry}` in the TeX header.