# Using huxtable labels in RMarkdown for PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, huxtable

I am using huxtable to display tables in RMarkdown for output: pdf_document.

When I put a label in the table

```
huxtable(mytable) %>%
set_label("tab:mylabel")
```

and then make a reference in the body text like

```
See Table \@ref(tab:mylabel) for more details
```

It displays "See Table @ref(tab:mylabel) for more details" rather than giving the table number.

This was covered for Bookdown in
[Huxtable package for R: How to correctly reference huxtables in bookdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868415/huxtable-package-for-r-how-to-correctly-reference-huxtables-in-bookdown)

Do I need some special option or other setting to make it work for a regular PDF document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems so. The [rmarkdown guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html) says you will need "a bookdown format" to use cross-referencing in that way. However, there's an alternative: use embedded TeX, rather than this rmarkdown format. A MWE:

````
```{r}
hux("A huxtable") %>% 
      set_label("tab:foo") %>% 
      set_caption("You'll need a caption too")
  
```

Here's a reference to \ref{tab:foo}.
````

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @dash2. Very easy when you know how.